# How to move skin directory to another place

Tags: php, magento

now i have such structure on my server

```
./site.com/
    ./site.com/mage
        ./site.com/mage/Mage.php
        ./site.com/mage/app
        .........
    ./site.com/public
        ./site.com/public/skin
        ./site.com/index.php
    ..........
```

`./site.com/public` is the apache root directory.
Magento still think skin directory in the same directory with app

I tried to change `default/system/filesystem/skin` entry in `./site.com/mage/etc/config.xml` but it does not help (Cache is disabled)

How i can change it?

Now im doing symlink from `public/skin` to `mage/skin` and its work, but its do not looks like better way.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my English :)

Comment: To clarify, you have a link named "skin" in `./site.com/mage/` which points to `../public/skin/`?

Comment: Yes, it's linux hard link.
Like cd ./site.com/mage/ 
ln -s ../public/skin ./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be worth having a look at Alan Storm's excellent site, specifically http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories. Note the comments at the foot:

> *Robbie:*
>   Can you change the base directories for themes? Magento defaults either to the /skin/frontend/base/... or the /app/design/frontend/base/...  I'd like to change that for the design and skin folders only.
>
> *alanstorm:*
>   No.  Or, more accurately, you might be able to but the system isn't designed to help you do this easily or via configuration.
>
> *Robbie:*
>   Collapse
>   Thanks Alan. I figured it would basically lock us into the current version of Magento.
>
> *Andrej Mocilnik:*
>   hi,
>   I want to change the paths  to var and media directories. To do so, do I have to modify the contstuctor code in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php?Is there a possibility to do that via config file?
>
> *alanstorm:*
>   That that I know of.

I know providing you a reason it is not advisable or easily achievable is not the same as providing you with an answer, but Alan is someone who is worth listening to when it comes to Magento.

Comment: Thank you, it at least something. I've already edit core, but im a little wondered about magento does not have ability to move application from root directory

Comment: There are some programatic assumptions that peg various paths to the application root.